# How do I create a mobile hotspot with two Wi-Fi adapters?

Tags: windows, networking, windows-10, wireless-networking

I want to create a Wi-Fi network hub with my Windows 10 machine with my extra Wi-Fi adapter. Some success, but I got stuck when I tried to connect the internal Wi-Fi to the Microsoft Hosted Network Virtual Adapter (MHVNA).

Steps I did:

1. Shut down internal Wi-Fi adapter because it doesn't support hosted mode.
2. Plug external Wi-Fi adapter into USB (Netgear)
3. Enable sharing for external Wi-Fi adapter in control panel “Wi-Fi 2” -> “Properties” -> “Sharing” -> “Allow other network users ...” -> Home networking = Local Area Connection* 14 (the MHNVA)
4. Enable the internal Wi-Fi adapter, connect it to Starbucks Wifi.
5. Connect with my iPhone to my SSID from the `netsh wlan set hostednetwork ...` command.

So far so good. I can ping my iPhone from a command prompt on my laptop.

My Problem: The iPhone cannot get to the internet. 
I don't know how to create a "bridge" or a route or whatever from the MHVNA to the internal Wi-Fi adapter.

(Why? - I have more than just the iPhone I want to connect to my laptop hotspot and I want them to be able to talk to each other. If I connect them all to Starbucks Wi-Fi then the (cisco?) Starbucks router doesn't allow traffic between them.)

Answer (score 0):

Okay, figured out my own problem. Kind of stupid, but whatever. Instead of enabling sharing for the external Wi-Fi adapter you should enable **internet** sharing for the internal Wi-Fi adapter. I didn't get that with all the other weirdness I was dealing with.

Answer (score 0):

As an answer to `I don't know how to create a "bridge" or a route or whatever from the MHVNA to the internal Wi-Fi adapter` even though:

1. You've solved your own problem already and
2. A network bridge wouldn't help accomplish what you've explained as
   your "why?" (and good thing you did include that because) in that
   that the devices would be able to use the internet when connecting
   to the device's MHVNA but would have applied the same network
   properties as if you just connected each device to the Starbucks
   wifi itself. A network bridge only provides a medium in which other
   devices can connect directly to the network and obtain the same IP
   address scheme every other computer connected to the network is
   using. It doesn't offer DHSCP and NAT so the ability of your devices
   talking to one another would rely on the settings of the router you
   are connected to the internet with which you've identified as not allowing discoverability.

*Because, I couldn't simply comment on your answer (which was just to mention how a bridge wouldn't help as explained above) due to lack of reputation on this particular StackExchange community while not wanting to violate the community rules with regard to adding an answer.*

For creating a network bridge, you would have to disable Internet Connection Sharing on the internal wifi adapter or adapter connected to the internet and then:

1. Go to Network Connections within the Control Panel (Either by changing view to All Control Panel Items or visiting the link for "Change Adapter Properties")
2. Select both adpaters you want to bridge by holding down the CTRL key
3. Right-click on either one of the adapters that's been selected and select Bridge Connections

Windows will then create what looks like another adapter to display the Network Bridge

Comment: Again, that doesn't give you the capabilities you ultimately were looking for but was to comment on how you wouldn't have wanted a bridge anyway. Though I upvoted your answer, my less than 15 reputation prevents my vote from being displayed. (Now I wonder if I have 50 reputation for being able to comment on my own or is it solely because it's my own answer that I can now comment?)